# Subsetting list in R using double square brackets

Tags: r, list, subset

After reading several threads about subsetting lists in R, I tried to fully grasp this notion by fooling around in Rstudio. I thought I understood the concept until I came across the following:

```
x <- list(list(list(1), 2), list(list(list(3), 4), 5), 6)
```

Why is it that `x[[1]]` returns a list with two elements and `x[[1]][[1]]` returns a list too?

Comment: You are subsetting the first list element which is also a nested list

Comment: I don't understand what were you expecting. `x[[1]]` returns a list with two elements because you have a list with two elements stored in the first slot of `x`.  But each time  the total depth of the nested list is decreasing. And that list has a list stored in the first slot so `x[[1]][[1]]` returns a list. (your command starts out with three nested `list()` calls). What were you expecting to be returned? Or what do you want to be returned?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you just write the definition of the list like this -

```
x <- list(
  list(
    list(1),
    2
  ),
  list(
    list(
      list(3),
      4
    ),
    5
  ),
  6
)
```

then it is easy to see that `x[[1]]` is

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 1


[[2]]
[1] 2
```

So `x[[1]]` comprises two elements - a list of one element 1, and the vector 2. `x[[1]][[1]]` extract the list of one element.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the code with two extra spaces to help make the structure more clear:

```
x <- list(  list( list(1), 2), list(list(list(3), 4), 5), 6)
```

The first element of x is: `list( list(1), 2)`  # clearly a list with two elements

And the first element of that list is: `list(1)`  # also a list but with one element

Answer (score 0):

Single brackets do subsetting.  Double brackets do extraction.

So `x[1]` is a single element list (`x` reduced to only its first element).

But you did `x[[1]]`, which extracts the first element from `x`, and it was a two element list as others explained.

`x[[1]][[1]]` extracts the first element from the first element of `x`.